# Adding a border to an element with border-radius

Tags: css

Funnily enough this isn't working for me in Firefox, Any ideas why the border isn't showing?

### CSS

```
.cue-points ul li a{
    text-indent:-9999px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 180px;
    -moz-border-radius: 180px;
    border-radius: 180px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    display:block;
    height:15px;
    width:15px;
}
```

### HTML

```
<a href="#one">One</a>
```

Comment: It does work http://jsfiddle.net/bBz7k/

Comment: I'm on firefox and it works well. 1. A http://www.jsfiddle.net showing the problem will be helpful. 2. You should mention what version of FF you're using

Comment: I realize you're trying to minimize your sample code, but does the CSS selector actually target the link?  In other words is it an anchor, that's a child of a list item, that's a child of an unordered list, that's a child of a cue-points class?

Comment: Works well. Note : `border-radius` doesn't require vendor prefixes anymore (since FF 4, Chrome 5)

Answer (score 0):

check your **.cue-points ul li a**

usually something is missing there
thsi wil work fine

```
a{
    text-indent:-9999px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 180px;
    -moz-border-radius: 180px;
    border-radius: 180px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    display:block;
    height:15px;
    width:15px;
}
```

and if you want to use clas you can just write

```
 .cue-points  a
```

or

```
 .cue-points  li a
```

demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/qLMH3/